# CSS3 animation on link

Tags: html, css

I have links that changes colors with a `:hover` state.

I have 4 links. They are Gray and turn Black when 'hovered'.

One of the links, I created a CSS3 animation to start off Black and slowly turn Gray. Yet, the original `:hover` state does not work.

Can I have the `:hover` state work on the link if I have CSS3 animation to it?

HTML code

```
<a href="#" class="Terms-Service">Terms of Service</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#">Use Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#">Anti-Spam Laws</a>
```

CSS code

```
a {
color: #7d7a78;
}
.login-section .bottom-links a:hover {
color: #4e4b49;
}

.Terms-Service {
-webkit-animation: go-black 5s 1;
animation: go-black 5s 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes go-black {
from {color: #4e4b49;}
to {color: #7d7a78;}
}
```

Comment: your code is not complete...check my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/wuwh6f55/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n2o7dvxz/ checkt this out are you trying to make hover with animation on one and rest just plain hover color change

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/wuwh6f55/2/ check it in chrome/firefox